# How to show items in array by using DOM ul li

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how can i do the exercise below?

Create an array of strings with your favorite dishes.
With js select a ul in the DOM. You add the ul to the html file.

Now loop through each element of the favorite dishes array, you create an li element and set the text to the favorite dish.

Then append the li element to the ul element.

my code is below:

```
const myDishes = ["lasagna", "steak", "pizza", "pasta", "bbq"];

const renderArray = myDishes.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item)
  })

function myFavDishes() {
  const ulTag = document.createElement('ul');
  const liTag = document.createElement('li');


    liTag.innerHTML = renderArray;
    ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
    //ulTag.document.appendChild(liTag);
    document.body.appendChild(ulTag);
}
myFavDishes();
```

html code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Favorite dishes</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="list">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="favorite-dishes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can achieve it like, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/Pozzaoe

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myDishes = ["lasagna", "steak", "pizza", "pasta", "bbq"];
function createDishes(name) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = name;
  return li;
}
const menu = document.querySelector(".list");
myDishes.forEach((x) => menu.appendChild(createDishes(x)));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Favorite dishes</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="list">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="favorite-dishes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you

```js
const myDishes = ["lasagna", "steak", "pizza", "pasta", "bbq"];



function myFavDishes() {
  const ulTag = document.createElement('ul');
    myDishes.forEach(item => {
      const liTag = document.createElement('li');
      liTag.innerHTML = item;
      ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(ulTag);
}
myFavDishes();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Favorite dishes</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! thanks for using my original code.